# find limit when x is infinity

Tags: calculus, limits

How can we find the following limit.
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}(x-\ln\cosh x)$$
where $$\cosh t=\frac{e^t+e^{-t}}{2}.$$

I thought about it alot but didn't get any start

Comment: Duplicate: [$\displaystyle\lim_{x\to \infty}\left(x-\ln\cosh x\right)=\ln 2$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1452299/201168). (*Found using [Approach0.xyz](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Clim_%7Bx%5Cto%5Cinfty%7D(x-%5Cln%5Ccosh%20x)%24&p=1)*)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can write our limit as , $$\ln(\lim_{x\to\infty}e^{x-\ln\cosh x})$$
$$=\ln (\lim_{x\to\infty}\dfrac{e^x}{\cosh x})$$
$$=\ln (\lim_{x\to\infty}\dfrac{2e^x}{e^x+e^{-x}})$$
$$=\ln (\lim_{x\to\infty}\dfrac{2}{1+e^{-2x}})$$
$$=\ln 2$$

---

Thus, $\lim_{x\to\infty}(x-\ln\cosh x)=\ln 2$

Comment: @Michael Burr Thank you for pointing that out. I have corrected it.

Answer (score 1):

Note that we have

$$\begin{align}
\log(\cosh(x))&=\log\left(\frac{e^x+e^{-x}}{2}\right)\\\\
&=x-\log(2)+\log(1+e^{-2x})
\end{align}$$

Hence, we can write

$$\lim_{x\to \infty}\left(x-\log(\cosh(x))\right)=\lim_{x\to \infty}\left(\log(2)-\log(1+e^{-2x})\right)=\log(2)$$